# How to upload file to a project directory using Spring MVC?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I need to upload image to dir in my project **webapp/resources/avatars**. It uploads me to my eclipse dir. What i need to do that it would upload images to project dir and after deploying my project! Help pls!
**Here is my controller method for uploading files:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postAvatar(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request)
{ 
    if(file.isEmpty())
    {
        return "redirect:/user";
    }
    System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
    String name=file.getOriginalFilename();
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {           
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            BufferedOutputStream stream =
                    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name)));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();

            System.out.println("You have uploaded file");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Failed to upload");
          return "redirect:/user";
        }
    }
    return"user";
}
```

**This is my dispatcher-servlet.xml file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd


     "
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">


    <context:component-scan base-package="
    com.vandh.app " />


    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/avatars/**" location="file:/resources/avatars"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>

                    <!-- Mail Sending properties -->
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <property name="port" value="587" />
        <property name="username" value="violandhate@gmail.com" />
        <property name="password" value="violenceandhate" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

        <bean id="multipartResolver"
   class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="5000000"/>
</bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>     
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">



        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using servlet context to get the absolute path as java.io is not aware of the context it is running. Try with the below option and let me know if it works. Also to make a note here, your images will be deleted when you redeploy the application. I hope you are aware of it..

```
@Autowired
    ServletContext context;
............

String relativeWebPath = "/resources/avatars";
String absoluteFilePath = context.getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
File uploadedFile = new File(absoluteFilePath, "your file name");
```

Comment: thanx for an answer but it saves me file with name **avatars+filename**.
`/home/acid_serg/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ViolenceAndHate/resources/avatarsiWankqCQJgQ.jpg`
smth like that

Comment: Use the file constructor `File(String pathname)` to just set the path. For comprehensive set of file constructors and api, please look into javadoc for File.

Comment: i fixed it. it downloads me to avatars folder. but id doesn't show (in eclipse) uploaded file into `/resource/avatars` folder. is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

Add directory when you save file:

```
BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("your_path" + name)));
```

Comment: thanx for an answer, but it gives me an exception and this catch works `catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Failed to upload");
          return "redirect:/user";
        }`

Comment: what kind of exception?

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: webapp/resources/avatars/myw3schoolsimage.jpg`

Comment: you need to try with different path -> I specified relative path, you need to specify yours or go with absolute path. For example: resources/avatars/ or /resources/avatars/. Try it.

Comment: nothing helps. also tried to use this path `src/main/webapp/resources/avatars`. No result. Same exception :(

Comment: maybe this path need to use when working with PC file system? not only with project dirs?

Comment: but what i need to do that i would save files into my project folders?

Comment: you need to provide absolute path to folder. Live (deployed) destination path will be different than local.

Comment: i need to make this fucntion after deploying on server?

Comment: No, you should have two different configuration, for live and dev